# Conserved currents for Lagrangian given by a trace

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, noethers-theorem, classical-field-theory

Let the Lagrange density $\mathcal{L}$ be given by
$\mathcal{L}=\mathrm{Tr}\left(\partial_\mu U^\dagger \partial^\mu U\right)$,
where $U=U(x)\in U(N)$. Suppose there are two matrices $A,B\in SU(N)$ and consider transformation $U(x)\rightarrow A^\dagger U(x)B$. One can easily check that $\mathcal{L}$ is invariant under such transformation, hence by Nother's theorem there exist conserved currents $j_{A,B}$ depended of choice of matrices $A,B$. My question is how to derive these currents ? I know the general formula given in the proof of Noether's theorem but I don't how to treat derivatives $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu U(x))}$ in this case. Moreover, we need to obtain $\delta U(x)$. I think the last one can be obtained using representation of $A,B$, which are near to unity, by the exponent of generators of appropriate Lie algebra.

Comment: This is evidently a trivial homework problem your instructor assigned to ensure you understand the symbols involved. Would it help you to write the matrices as sums of the respective two indices of the respective two matrices *U* and its h.c.? If the two matrices are in *U(N)*, they are expandible around the identity, *A* ~ $1\!\!\!1 +iaT$, so then $\delta U= ia T U$, etc... exploiting the cyclicity of the trace, don't you have your answer? You only need appreciate what Gursey's elegant chiral notation actually means.

Comment: This is an exercise which I found reading a book about field theory. I tried to expand $A\sim 1+i\sum_{j}^{N^2-1}a_j T^j$, but now I see it is enough to take $A\sim 1+iaT$ as you wrote. The question is how to treat the derivative ? $U(N)$ is not a Banach space - we cannot calculate it.

Comment: ***Banach***? Aren't you overthinking it? I encouraged you to take derivatives w.r.t. matrix elements. In any case, in any way you like, see how you obtain the right-invariant, so *left* current $j_A\propto i U\partial_\mu U^\dagger$ and the right, so left-invariant one, $j_B \propto i U^\dagger \partial_\mu U $.

Comment: Ok. My main problem was what it the meaning of $\frac{\partial}{\partial (\partial_\mu U)}$, where $U\in U(N)$ or more generally, if $G$ is a Lie group and $g\in G$ what is $\frac{\partial}{\partial (\partial_\mu g)}$. The problem of thinking of it directly is that we do not have a linear structure on $U(N)$, so formally we don't know how to understand these derivatives. To sum up, these derivatives means $\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial (\partial_\mu U_{ab})}\right)_{a,b}$, right ?

Comment: I'm still baffled as to what is bothering you and why you imagine there is no (bi)linear structure. Do you not read this Tr$\partial_\mu  U^\dagger \partial_\mu U=\sum_{a,b}\partial_\mu  U^\dagger_{ab} \partial_\mu U_{ba} $? So you consider each $U_{ab}$ as a separate variable, properly interpreting the h.c. partner.

Comment: There is no linear structure on $U(N)$ (for example $U(1)$ is a circle, which is not a linear topological space - if we add $r\in U(1)$ to $-r\in U(1)$ then we obtain $0$, which not belong to the circle). We can define differentiation only w.r.t. elements of linear space (sometimes we also required Banach structure), so we cannot define $\frac{\partial}{\partial U}$  for $U\in U(N)$ etc. Now I understand what this symbol means, but in my book it was not defined. I tried to think of $U(x)$ as one variable instead of $U_{ab}$ as separate variables. I will try to do it as you wrote. Thanks!

Comment: @CosmasZachos I don't think the above is a "trivial homework problem", though. Noether theorem relates groups of *continuous* symmetries to conservation laws: in the case at hand, having $U(N)$ finite dimensional representations, every operator can be finely decomposed onto its basis and the trace can be calculated summing over the diagonal terms, as you showed, without worrying about strong convergence in the operator sense. In case of groups of operators not possessing trivial finite-dimensional representations, instead, the problem is non-trivial...

Comment: ...and it would be worth spending few more words on what it means for such a Lagrangian to undergo a transformation of the type shown above.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco  I'm not sure what you are after. The principal chiral models are the bread and butter of flavor dynamics effective FTs in particle physics, and the flavor group is a finite *N*  *SU(N)*. The *U* s are dumb small dimensional matrices involving mesons. The fundamental rep for *N* ⟶  ∞ is, indeed, infinite dimensional, but can be gotten smoothly in that limit.  To the extent *A* and *B* are group elements of *SU(N)*, they are basically exp( *ia · T* ) s, so then  continuous groups.  The invariance of the Lagrangian is manifest. Any self-respecting QFT text covers them.

Comment: Arguably section 3 of our [older paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Cosmas_Zachos/publication/223877745_Torsion_and_geometrostasis_in_nonlinear_sigma_models/links/09e4150aba5578993e000000.pdf) reviews and interprets these models geometrically, to your satisfaction, or not....

Comment: @CosmasZachos Maybe you didn't read my comment above thoroughly. In case of $SU(N)$ everything is obviously trivial. In case of different groups the matter may become non-trivial according to the structure the group and its representations have, as it may become non-trivial to even define what a continuous symmetry for that group is. I just wanted to remark that although the exercise might be solved brute-force summing over the trace, the question itself is not.

Comment: Still cannot second-guess what you might possibly be after. If you posted an independent question on this, make sure you define each term unambiguously.

Comment: The are different ways to compute the Noether current. One can for instance use the path integral approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that it is tagged as a homework exercise, I'm probably not supposed to solve the problem, but I can give some hints as to how I would tackle the problem. Assuming one wants to use the standard approach to derive the Noether current, I would suggest that one does not overthink the problem and simply treat the $U$'s as (matrix-valued) functions. One can then apply the derivatives as functional derivatives in the usual way (but I'll use the normal notation for derivatives). One would need a rule for applying the functional derivatives. Making the indices of the matrices explicit, one would have
$$ \frac{\partial [U(x)]_{ab} }{\partial[U(y)]_{cd}} = \delta(x-y)\delta_{a}^{c}\delta_{b}^{d} . $$
You can now generalize this to the case where $U$ is replaced by $\partial_{\mu} U$.

Another important thing to remember is that the derivative of the adjoint is not zero.
$$ \frac{\partial U^{\dagger} }{\partial U}\neq 0 . $$

For this one can use
$$ U^{\dagger} = U^{\dagger}UU^{\dagger} . $$

If you still get stuck, let me know, then I can perhaps expand on some of these points.